# Sidebar Menu is not displayed in custom page which is extending admin/base.html

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

I Have created a custom page which I want to display in Django Admin Panel. I am using `jazzmin` admin template for my django project.

**Problem:**
I am not getting the sidebar menu only option I can see is Dashboard. Why is this happening and how do I get full sidebar menu which I am getting for all the page for the models registered in `admin.py`

My Views.py

```py
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, NewTopic
from base.constants import KAFKA_CONFIG
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Create your views here.
KAFKA_EXCLUDE_TOPICS = {'__consumer_offsets': True}


class QueueOperationsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dataprocessing/queue_management/queue.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        admin_client = AdminClient(KAFKA_CONFIG)
        topic_metadata = admin_client.list_topics()
        has_purge_permissions = self.request.user.has_perm('masters.purge_dataprocessingqueuemaster')

        # add your context data here
        context['topics'] = [i for i in topic_metadata.topics if i not in KAFKA_EXCLUDE_TOPICS]
        context['has_purge_permissions'] = has_purge_permissions
        return context
```

My Urls.py

```py
from basics.admin import wrap_admin_view
from masters.views import QueueOperationsView
from django.conf.urls import url

url(r'^admin/queue-management/$', wrap_admin_view(QueueOperationsView.as_view()), name="queue_operations_view"),
```

wrap_admin_view():

```py
def wrap_admin_view(view, cacheable=False):
    """
    Use this to wrap view functions used in admin dashboard
    Note: Only the views that require a admin login
    """
    from django.contrib import admin

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return admin.site.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.admin_site = admin.site
    return update_wrapper(wrapper, view)
```

Template:

```html
{% extends 'admin/base.html'%}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">

    
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block additional_scripts %}
{{ block.super }}
{% include "dataprocessing/queue_management/queue_management_options.html" %}
{% include "dataprocessing/queue_management/queue_management_table.html" %}
{% include "dataprocessing/queue_management/queue_management_table_loading.html" %}
<script src="{% static 'js/admin/queue_management/queue_management.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue myself today. For some reason, I had to provide the list of available apps in the context. I did this inside of a view method, so I'm not sure if it's 100% applicable to what you have written, but this was my solution.

```
context = {"available_apps": self.admin_site.each_context(request).get("available_apps")}
```